# String Array Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, string

It's simple but I've confused at somewhere.

Let's say, we have `string array` with `size 5`. And we did;

```
array[0]="ted"
array[4]="barney"
```

So elements are;

```
 {"ted", null, null, null, "barney"}
```

If I use `Arrays.sort`, what will be the *new position* of `new sorted array`?

```
1-) barney, ted, null, null, null  

2-) null, null, null, barney, ted

3-) barney, null, null,null, ted
```

**which one?**

thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: This can be easily test by yourself. No ?

Comment: do you interest in why so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by running the given code.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
```

because String and null are not comparable to each other

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of simple testable questions, the best way to have an answer is to run the code yourself on a new empty project.

And to answer your question, the result will be a NullPointerException because null is not a Comparable

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }});
```

This is how you can sort it and get the results of : barney, ted, null, null, null.  else you will get a null pointer exception.